# Search for string LIKE wildcards and variables - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I search in the database for users with emails following a variable?

For example, I would like to see all users with emails ending in @statusquo.org

I would like the search to allow me to store this email in a variable, so that it can be flexible. The following query doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @emailAddress = '@statusquo.org'
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_address LIKE '%' + @emailAddress
```

It returns nothing, probably because it interprets the variable as 1 character. How can I make this run correctly?

Comment: Declare @emailAddress varchar(100) = '@statusquo.org'   ... ALWAYS declare your variable with a datatype and length/precision

Comment: `DECLARE @emailAddress = '@statusquo.org'` is not valid, but I'm guessing you actually have `DECLARE @emailAddress varchar = '@statusquo.org'`